# Measure that agrees with Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $\mu $ is a measure defined on $(\mathbb{R} , \mathcal{B}( \mathbb{R}) ) $ such that $\mu (I) =\lambda (I) $ for every interval $I$ of $\mathbb{R} $ (where $\lambda $ is the Lebesgue measure) then how can I show $\mu =\lambda $.
While looking for this I came across the monotone class theorem. This does the trick but I was wondering whether there was quite a simple way to extend the result from intervals to any borel set.
I also thought about proving it using the fact that the smallest dynkin class generated a $\pi - $ system is precisely the smallest sigma algebra generated by the pi system.
But can we say that {$A \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R}) : \mu(A) =\lambda (A) \
 $} is a dynkin class - I'm unsure as the measures are not finite.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm wrong you need additional hypothesis : translation invariance and scaling property

Comment: Translation invariance and $\mu ((0,1))=1$ is assumed yes

Comment: By scaling I meant $\mu(\lambda A)=\lambda\mu(A)$, but okay :) Edit : very bad choice of notation with mu and lambda but you get the point !

Comment: Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq . The key is the regularity of $\lambda$. See my A.

Answer (score 1):

(1).  For $E\subset \Bbb R$ let $O_E$ be the set of all open $O$ such that $E\subset O ,$  and let $C_E$ be the set of all compact $C$ such that $C\subset E.$ For any measure $m$ with $dom(m) \supset \mathcal B(\Bbb R),$ let $m^o(E)=\inf \{m(O): O\in O_E\}$ and $m^i(E)=\sup\{m(C):C\in C_E\}.$ Obviously, if $E\in dom(m)$ then $m^i(E)\le m(E)\le m^o(E).$

(2). $\mu$ agrees with $\lambda$ on bounded intervals, so $\mu$ agrees with $\lambda$ on any convex set $L$ because $L=\cup M$ where $M=\{L\cap [z,z+1):z\in \Bbb Z\}$ is a countable pairwise-disjoint family of bounded intervals.

(3). For any open $O$ there is a countable pairwise-disjoint family $G$ of convex open sets with $O=\cup G,$ so by (2) we have $\lambda(O)=\sum_{g\in G}\lambda(g)=\sum_{g\in G}\mu(g)=\mu(O).$

(4). By (3), therefore $\lambda^o(E)=\mu^o(E)$ for any $E\subset \Bbb R. $

(5). For any compact $C\subset \Bbb R$ take  a bounded open interval $J$ with $C\subset J. $ and let $D=J \setminus C.$ Then $D$ is also open so by (3) we have  $\mu(C)+\lambda(D)=\mu(C)+\mu(D)=\mu(J)=\lambda(J)=\lambda(C)+\lambda(D).$

So $\mu(C)=\lambda(C).$

(6). Let $E\subset \Bbb R$ be bounded.  Let $J$ be a bounded open interval with $\overline E\subset J.$ Let $C'_E=\{C\in C_E:C\subset J\}.$ Then by (5) we have $\mu^i(E)=\sup \{\mu(C): C\in C'_E\} =\sup  \{\lambda(C):C\in C'_E\}=\lambda^i(E).$

(7). $\lambda$ is outer-regular and inner-Radon-regular. That is, if $E\in dom(\lambda)$ then $\lambda(E)=\lambda^o(E)=\lambda^i(E).$ So if $E$ is a bounded Borel set then by (6) and (4):$$\lambda(E)=\lambda^i(E)=\mu^i(E)\le \mu(E)\le \mu^o(E)=\lambda^o(E)=\lambda(E)$$ and therefore $\mu(E)=\lambda(E).$ So for any Borel set $E$ we have $$\mu(E)=\sum_{z \in \Bbb Z}\mu(E\cap [z,z+1)\,)=\sum_{z\in \Bbb Z}\lambda(E\cap [z,z+1)\,)=\lambda(E).$$